# What are these white things on my Salvia

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

Today while looking at my Salvia bush, I found it covered in these white round things. What are they?
Their shape and size isn't regular, ranging from a couple mm to a cm in diameter and generally round. Some completely surround the stem while others are only on one side.

I am at the north end of California's San Joaquin valley

[image: while thing just right of center, and another in the lower righ]
[image: many white things in the center with a few throughout the picture]

Comment: Is the white stuff foamy/bubbly like spit? If so, it could be spittlebugs.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx Looking at pictured of Spittlebug nymphs, it looks like you're right. If you want to put an answer up, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like spittlebugs. They produce a bubbly spit-like substance around themselves for protection from heat, predators, etc. Your reply to me question seems to confirm this. Apparently, they can be plant-sucking pests, but I've only seen them on rare occasions in small numbers before (mostly in my childhood on giant garden weeds), and the plants didn't seem threatened (but weeds are resilient, and I was a child).

Comment: It was indeed foamy and when I looked closer I could see the nymphs in the smaller ones. Apparently they're rare in this large a quantity and only damage plants in large numbers